# Programmatically 'press' button every 60 seconds

Tags: android, timer

In my app, I've been asked to add an auto update function.  What I'm trying to do is have a timer event so that if the user hasn't pressed the update button in the last 60 seconds, do a  'refreshButton.performClick();'.

I've been searching but I can't find an example where the timer interacts with the UI.  I keep getting errors like 'only the original thread that created a view hierarchy'.

If the user does press the button, I want to reset the timer.

Is this even possible?

Comment: paste your existing code so we can help you to modify/extend it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only can interact with aView from the UI thread.

You can make something like this in your timer task;

- Define this variable in your class:

  `Handler handler = new Handler();`
- In your timer task call:

  ```
    handler.post(new Runnable(){ 
         public void run(){  
             refreshButton.performClick();  
         }
    });
  ```

Comment: Or even better, call `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);`. To avoid the timer entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going in the wrong direction. Instead of trying to press the button, just set a timer to call the same method that is called once the button is pressed, it will make it way simpler, and will not involve the UI for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlaramManager class and a background service to run your code on every 60 second.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm) is an example see AlarmService_Service.java

Comment: This would cause the update to happen even if the app had been exited. sgallegos answer is imho better and easier to implement. 

"The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have  your application code run at a specific time, even if your  application is not currently running"

Comment: you can stop alaram service in onDestroy method of your activity simply.

Comment: @ Jave you are right sgallegos method is better and easy to implement.